# Oracle Publish/Subscribe using Topic

Tags: jms-topic, oracle-soa, oracle-bpm-suite

I'm facing some problems using Oracle JMS Adapter. I have a Bpel process that is publishing a message on a topic queue using JMS Adapter, this is working, the problem is on subscribing this message. I have two BPM process that is
subscribing from this queue but only one is taking the message. I'm using the same JMS Adapter for the two process.

I've removed the BPM process that was working and left only the other that was not subscribing and it could subscribe. My question is:

How can I make this two BPM process subscribe from the topic together? Everything is working properly since with one process it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create two JMS Adapter, after that everething worked.

I also put at Oracle Community:
[enter link description here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4123975)